# Problems with Ansible and GitHub

Tags: git, github, ssh, ansible

I have dug through the internet and tried everything. I've tried:

```
- name: ensure github.com in known host
  shell: ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> /home/{{ deploy_user }}/.ssh/known_hosts
```

and:

```
[ssh_connection]
ssh_args = -o ForwardAgent=yes
```

I also tried using the `key_file` attribute on the git module, the only option I seem to be left with is to copy the the public key from the server and add it to github, but this will make scaling hard and slow. No matter what I do, I get:

> Permission denied (publickey).\r\nfatal: Could not read from remote repository.\n\nPlease make sure you have the correct access rights\nand the repository exists.

Comment: When I change my url from git@github.com:<username>/<project>.git to git://github.com/<username>/<project>.git I get 

```fatal: remote error: \n  Repository not found.```

Comment: I even tried the method mentioned here https://www.claudiokuenzler.com/blog/604/clone-a-private-git-repository-with-ansible-password-prompt#.WBQ37eErJE4

Comment: You are confusing server authentication with user authentication. From the blog link you posted in comments (btw you should specify this in your question, not comments), it looks like you don't want to use public-key authentication, yet the error message clearly states you are using it. Your troubleshooting went astray and you have posted information completely irrelevant to your problem. Edit the question with your complete playbook and the results you get.

Answer (score 0):

> the only option I seem to be left with is to copy the the public key from the server and add it to github

Ansible or not, if you are using a public ssh key, said key has to [be declared to a GitHub account setting](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/) if you want any ssh call to `github.com` to succeed (without falling back to the username/password authentication scheme)

And you don't add a public key to "github.com" authorized_keys directly, but you need to use [GitHub create key API](https://developer.github.com/v3/users/keys/#create-a-public-key) to register a new one.
See "[Ansible Module - Github Keys](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-extras/pull/211)"

Comment: I tried using the github_key module, but it said it could not find the github_key module. http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/github_key_module.html

Comment: The module github_key was not found in configured module paths. Additionally, core modules are missing. If this is a checkout, run 'git submodule update --init --recursive' to correct this problem. I installed it using homebrew

Comment: @brianthecoder so did `'git submodule update --init --recursive` fix the problem?

Comment: No, I went to the directory of the homebrew install and got ```fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git``` can it only be installed by pip now? Homebrew used to work